# $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) is not a valid bundle identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I'm porting a Chrome extension to Safari. I can test the extension locally, it works. I can also build it locally, I get no errors.

When I try to upload it to App Store Connect, I get the following errors:

[image]

This doesn't make much sense to me. I do have valid Bundle identifiers set in my Targets > General > Identity:

[image]

[image]

But somehow my bundle identifiers do not seem to get applied when an archive is built. I am very new to XCode. Any tips on how to debug and/or fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check Info.plist for your extension.

Comment: @RobZombie That's where I have these variables, $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER), $(PRODUCT_NAME) —  but these don't seem to be resolved in the build process. How can I change that?

Comment: left the answer below since it's difficult to post screenshots otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not solved by the above suggested questions. It turns out that I had to port the Chrome extension again, using the most recent XCode. (The original porting happened using an earlier version of XCode).

Answer (score 2):

Your bundle identifier has a hyphen in it. That's what's illegal about it.

Answer (score 0):

Click on project at the top of the source file tree in the left sidebar, select the target in a mini sidebar on the left, and switch to `Build Settings`. In build settings select the following filter: All, Combined.

Then type in the following in the search bar on the right hand side: `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` and verify that both Release and Debug configurations have sane values set. Then do the same for `PRODUCT_NAME`.

[image: Build settings]